# Phpstan fails with "Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ';' " in definition of function

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, phpstan

I am using Phpstan on a Drupal project that needs to be updated; I have solved all the issues revealed by Phpstan except one and I don´t know the solution to that one.

The error message is:

```
Line   asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php                    
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------- 
  32     Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ';' on line 32
```

The code mentionned here is the following function:

```
private array $defaultOptions void   (
        'allowedHeaders'         => array(),
        'allowedMethods'         => array(),
        'allowedOrigins'         => array(),
        'allowedOriginsPatterns' => array(),
        'exposedHeaders'         => false,
        'maxAge'                 => false,
        'supportsCredentials'    => false,
    );
```

where as line 32 is the following line:

```
private array $defaultOptions void   (
```

I am absolutely sure about the line numbers and code parts mentionned py Phpstan, however I am not sure about the solution for this problem and hence, any help or hints would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: An array is defined with `array()` or brackets `[]`, not `()`, and would not have a return type. Functions do not start with a `$`

Comment: Missing `= [ ... ]` or `= array( ... )` after `$defaultOptions`. Also, `void` is a return type, and is out of place here unless there's some new syntax I'm missing? If you wanted the property as nullable, you could declare it as `private ?array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what happened here, but the code is completely wrong. It's supposed to be an array definition, not a function. From the source code at https://github.com/asm89/stack-cors/blob/master/src/Cors.php, the definition should be

```
 private $defaultOptions = [
        'allowedHeaders'         => [],
        'allowedMethods'         => [],
        'allowedOrigins'         => [],
        'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
        'exposedHeaders'         => [],
        'maxAge'                 => 0,
        'supportsCredentials'    => false,
    ];
```

If this file is in the vendor folder, set it back to the original and **do not change it**. Anything in the vendor folder should be managed by the developers, since the next time you run `composer update` and there's a new version, it will overwrite any changes you've made. If there's an issue with a library you've included or is part of the original package, contact the developers instead.